# RULE_APPEND failed (iptables)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, iptables

I'm working on an assignment in which I have to create some custom firewall rules on a Debian router. I'm using iptables to create the rules. Here's the thing, whenever I try to add this rule: `iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --destination-port 20:443 -s 192.168.2.107 -j ACCEPT` I get this error: `RULE_APPEND failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain FORWARD`, I've been trying to solve this problem for like 5 hours now and can't get around it, can someone help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the *iptables* match module *tcp* is expecting to be called for the *tcp protocol* case only, selected with the `-p tcp` option, but it wasn't. This mistake is rarely happening, because usually only `-p tcp` is written, which automatically loads the `-m tcp` match module.

This can be seen with this kernel's `dmesg` line:

```
 x_tables: ip_tables: tcp match: only valid for protocol 6
```

where protocol 6 means *tcp* (as can be found in `/etc/protocols`). This message triggers both with *iptables-nft* (that you are using) and *iptables-legacy* because even the nft version  uses the kernel xtables module (`xt_tcpudp.ko`). The legacy version's error message would have been more helpful with:

```
iptables: Invalid argument. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

So to fix your rule, that would be:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p tcp -m tcp --destination-port 20:443 -s 192.168.2.107 -j ACCEPT
```

and actually the `-m tcp` is optional (and also the obsolete `-m state --state` can be replaced with superseding `-m conntrack --ctstate`).